# Building a Q&A app in rails, I am a bit unsure about how to send questions to a specific user

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, model

As the title suggests, I am building a Q&A application (Like ask.fm) in Ruby on Rails, and I am having some trouble with sending the question to a specific user.

I have 3 models, a User model (from Devise), A Question model with this attribute: content:text and a Answer model with this attribute: content:text

Here are their models

```
class Answer < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :question
  belongs_to :user
 end

class Question < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :answer
  belongs_to :user
end

 class User < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :questions
   has_many :answers
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
    devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
     :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable
  end
```

And here are the migrations that I created

This one adds a user_id to the question (So I can check which user sent the question, btw this works fine)

```
 class AddUserIdToQuestion < ActiveRecord::Migration
   def change
     add_column :questions, :user_id, :integer
   end
 end
```

Here I tried to add a receiver (the user that would get the question) but I wont work, when I create a Question It will be equal to 'nil', when I check it out in the rails console (Check the controller to see what I did)

```
class AddReceiverToQuestion < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :questions, :receiver, :integer
  end
end
```

Here is the question controller

```
  class QuestionsController < ApplicationController

def new
    @question = Question.new
end

def create
    @question = Question.new(question_params)   
    @question.user_id = current_user.id

    if @question.save
        redirect_to root_path
    else
        render 'new'
    end
end



private

def question_params
    params.require(:question).permit(:content, :user_id)
end
end
```

I also have a user profile page where I have a form show up, here is the controller for that one

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController

def show
  @user = User.find(params[:id])
  @user_questions = @user.questions
  @question = Question.new
end

def create
  @user = User.find(params[:id])

  @question = Question.new(question_params) 
  @question.receiver = @user.id #This does not work 
  if @question.save
      redirect_to root_path
  else
      render 'new'
  end
 end



private

def question_params
    params.require(:question).permit(:content, :user_id, :receiver)
end

 end
```

I really hope some of you know what I could do here, thank you :)

Comment: `@question.receiver = @user` should work

Comment: Just tried it out. It is still nil, Do you know if I have to save it some place. It seems like the receiver doesn't save anything

Comment: Ah, it's an integer column. Should be a `receiver_id` instead. And put `belongs_to :receiver, class_name: 'User'` into question.

Comment: Then how would I go about changing the receiver to receiver_id

Comment: should I do a rake db:rollback

Comment: @Sergio I tried it. I ran `rake db:rollback` changed up the migration from `:receiver to :receiver_id`, and then I ran `rake db:migrate`, then I added this line `belongs_to :receiver, class_name: 'User'` to the question model and in my user controller I have this set `@question.receiver_id = @user`. And the receiver_id is nil

Comment: It seems that you're flying blind. Read this guide, it should help: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev It seems like i can't set the value for the receiver_id. I can set the receiver_id on a specific question in the console but how would I declare it in code?

Comment: @SergioTulentsev Yes that's what I tried. But where should I set the value of receiver_id, I tried setting it in the controller but it always returns nil, even if I set the value manually to 1